# Learning .Net core 5 project

Tags: asp.net-core

I am following this link:

```
https://github.com/psauthor/CoreApiFundamentals/tree/5.0
```

To learn a .net core 5 project structure. The project is simple and easy to follow. When I run by clicking on IIS Express it runs in the Browser and all I need to do is to add /api/values to the url and I get some data back. Now I am trying to create a web on IIS by creating new website in IIS Manager. I am assigning it some port and specifying a physical path to the net5.0 folder where all the dlls are. Which for me is: C:\solutionfolder\projectfolder\bin\Release\net5.0
But running it in the browser like this:

```
http://localhost:8085/api/values
```

gives me 404. so, is it possible to run that project the way I am trying?

Thanks

Update. I found this article:
[Deploy ASP.NET Core Web API on IIS](https://codingsonata.medium.com/deploy-asp-net-core-web-api-on-iis-f75e755a6402)

But even after that the URL:

```
localhost:8085/nameofcontroller
```

still gives me 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deploy your ASP.NET Core API project to a folder from Visual Studio, the default folder location would be `bin\Release\net5.0\publish\`, like below.

[image]

To host it on IIS, you can try to select that website in IIS Manager and modify the site's physical path to `C:\solutionfolder\projectfolder\bin\Release\net5.0\publish`.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that what I did. The missing piece was processPath="projectname.exe" in the  web.config